# How to make expandable composite, while dragging our custom new Wizard

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

Thanks in advance.

I am creating one GUI on new wizard, that is available in eclipse by default, in wizard page i m creating GUI in createControl method , now for that i am creating one composite that is child of parent in that i have to create two composite from left to right in which left one should only expand horizantally and right one should expand in both directions horizantally and vertically

Now in left composite i have to display images located in c drive location and when user clicks on images displayed in left composite , in right composite specific images will load .

Now functionality i have completed using rcp , used fill layout for both composite and scrolled composite and  row layout for inner composites that displays images with label , now the same logic i am implementing in wizard page  but GUI is nonexpandable ......it sucks.......i tried every layout but i don't know where i m lagging ....as i m newbee in GUI ...:(

My problem is how to display two composite in wizard page , where first is only vertically expandable , and other one is expandable in both directions, and display images in these composites , that are located in my c drive ........

Answer (score 0):

The parent composite layout shoud be grid layout. For the left child composite, set it layoutdata to be vertical expand. As for the right composite, set it to fill both.
Hope this help.

Comment: but at the bottom i've to  create one text field , one browse button, and  after some gap one text field and label, now i m using grid layout but problem is with the number of columns i m using , as composites alligns properly but the bottom portions all these get troubled , so how to allign bottom parts , as i mentioned above , thanks.....